# Why is constant initialization need for static char* but not static char**

Tags: c, compiler-errors, initialization

Can someone please explain why this code...

```
// main.c

#include <stddef.h>

static const int    g_a   = 1;
static const char*  g_b   = "hello";
static const char*  g_c[] = { "a",    "b",    NULL };

typedef struct Foo
{
  int           a;
  const char*   b;
  const char**  c;
} Foo;

static Foo f[] =
{
  { g_a,
    g_b,
    g_c }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  return 0;
}
```

...produces this error:

```
> gcc --version && gcc -g main.c 
gcc (GCC) 8.2.1 20181215 (Red Hat 8.2.1-6)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

main.c:19:5: error: initializer element is not constant
     g_b,
     ^~~
main.c:19:5: note: (near initialization for 'f[0].b')
```

I understand that the compiler is asking for a *constant* to initialize `f[0].b`, so the following initialization is a solution to the compile error:

```
static Foo f[] = { { g_a, "hello", g_c } };
```

But **why does the compiler not issue a similar "constant required" error for the initialization of `f[0].c`?** (Or, for that matter, `f[0].a`?) **Why is this only an issue for `f[0].b`?**

Comment: That would compile in C++. In C, however, you'll need to replace those compile-time constants with preprocessor-time constants (i.e., using `#define`).

Comment: @goodvibration - thank you, understood, but I'm specifically curious why that only applies to the `char*` but not the `char**`

Comment: If you make g_c a pointer instead of an array (and point it somewhere valid), it will become invalid as a const initializer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f[0].a` has type "non-constant `int`" and is initialized by the value of `g_a` that is of type "const `int`" which cannot change at run time and is known at compile time. So no error here.

`f[0].b` has type "non-constant pointer to `const char`" and should be initialized by the value of `g_b` that is also a "non-constant pointer to `const char`". Even if it has an initializer `g_b` can change at run time, and IIRC the initialization sequence is not determined. So its value is not known at compile time, hence the error.

`f[0].c` has type "non-constant pointer to non-constant pointer(s) to `const char`" and is initialized by `g_c` that is an array of elements of type "non-constant pointer to `const char`". The symbol of an array can be used as a constant pointer which is known at compile time. So no error here.

**This is what you are missing, I think:** If you want a pointer to be `const`, place the modifier at the pointer, behind the `*`, not at the pointed value, like  this: `[const] char * const pointer`.

Comment: Alas, this looked promising because the suggestion worked with one of my cross-compilers, but it appears to be compiler-specific, because it fails on others. On the failing compilers, it reports the same, unchanged, compile error. I guess I'll have to resort to `#define`s.

Answer (score 1):

Formal definitions: look at the 'address constant' definition: "C Language refence manual 6.19":

> The address constant is a pointer to an object that has static storage
>   duration or a pointer to a function. You can get these by using the &
>   operator or through the usual conversions of array and function names
>   into pointers when they are used in expressions. The operators [], .,
>   ->, & (address of) and * (pointer dereference) as well as casts of pointers can all be used in the expression as long as they don't
>   involve accessing the value of any object.

Practical answer: "C" requires that static variable are initialized to constant expression which can be calculated at compile time. The constant calculation can use addresses of static/global variables - where the actual address is not known until link time.

In those cases (e.g., char *char_p = &char_var, or similar), the compiler will generate assembly instructions to mark the calculated value for 'relocation' at link time. The relocation as expressed by a static/global variable. At link time, the linker will add the actual address of the static/global to the stored value.

Consider: `char char_var = 'A' ; char *char_p = &char_var;`

```
        .file   "b.c"
        .text
        .globl  char_var
        .data
        .type   char_var, @object
        .size   char_var, 1

   # Char var initialized with a constant (65=A)
char_var:
        .byte   65
        .globl  char_p
        .section        .data.rel.local,"aw",@progbits
        .align 8
        .type   char_p, @object
        .size   char_p, 8

    # Initialize char_p to global symbol, actual address resolved at link time.
char_p:
        .quad   char_var

        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

There is limit to the to the linker ability to calculate address at link time. It is limited to static address +/- constant offsets:

1. &static_var
2. &static_var + compile time constant
3. &static_var - compile time constant

But not '&static_var_1 - &static_var_2', which will give an error message hinting at the limit:
`b.c:3:9: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
 int v = &char_var - &char_v2 ;`